# How to create a DialogFragment with a transparent part?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

How should I create the superior part of this design?
I'm doing it in a popup using a DialogFragment, but I can't not achieve the effect of transparency at the top.

[image]

The button design but background_circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#fff"/>

</shape>
```

With the following XML file my_dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text long text"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_circle"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_star"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

The star must be with the superior part outside of the layout.

Comment: Just use a fragment.

Comment: using a transparent activity would help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy.. my friend

[image]

just set default dialog background to transparent as I did in onStart()

```
class TestDialog: DialogFragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, container)
        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            // if you want your dialog's width/height match device screen's width/height
            // dialog?.window?.setLayout(
            //    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            //    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            // )

            dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        }
    }
```

**Your dialog .xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text long text"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_circle"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_54dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**background_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#fff"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: with the relative layout I couldn't obtain the desired effect. Look at the update

Comment: the problem is your image size. In my case, I used a drawable file that has 
width = 54dp and height = 54dp. This means you should change your imageView's width & height from wrap_content to a fixed size, Eg: 54dp. Let see the result

Comment: You also need to add this line in onStart() of your DialogFragment class

dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

Comment: thanks, dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))  this was the missing line!

Answer (score 1):

It could be rough solution, but how about using  blurry view behind popup view?

Check this library.

https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView